# Android_Increased Version code and Version name

Tags: java, android, path, google-play, updates

I've increased my apk's version code and name in manifest.xml and then uploaded on (google play) Developer Console but I couldn't released on beta. Only thing I can do is just storage temporarily on beta test and I think google don't recognize my uploaded apk because nothing is changed when i get in to the tester URL.

Did i miss something that i have to change on Java code or some files? 
My zipfilepath on java code is :

```
   zipFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
+"/Android/obb/"+thePackageName+"/main."+thePackageVer+"."+thePackageName+".obb";
```

I've set all path and file names that google wants. Did i really miss something?

Comment: "but I couldn't released on beta": what happened? Did you get an error message? Otherwise it maybe just takes some time to show up (1-2 hours usually).

Comment: @Henry no i didn't get any error message but it's mysterious because i can see the two kinds of button when i upload on beta test. One is "released on beta" and the other one is "temporary storage" but i couldn't see the former. I've waited 7-8 hours but nothing happened :-(